# is there a way to to account for time-varying covariates in a negative binomial hurdle model?

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, missing-data, zero-inflation

i am investigating smoking exposure (0,1) and caries outcome (count data, 0-28). I am using a negative binomial hurdle regression model (considering excess zeros in outcome) for my analysis

Model 1:

caries@~ smoking@5years+ + alcohol + education

I also have a smoking variable at 1 year. Knowing that if I include it in my model as a seperate variable would it overestimate my results?
Is there a way to account for time varying covariates in my hurdle model? If so how do I implement in R

Is there also a way of accounting for repeated measurements of caries as well